# Why doesn't this Regex match any of the dates?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re

I'm trying to match dates in a dataframe with 500 entries using regex:

The dates can appear in the following formats:

```
04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010
```

---

```
dates[dates[0].str.contains(r'(?P<year>\d?\d?\d\d)')].shape
```

returns a tuple of `shape(500,1)`

but

```
dates[dates[0].str.contains(r'((?P\<day\>(\d?\d)?(\s|-|/|th|st|nd)?)??P\<year\>(\d?\d?\d\d))')].shape
```

returns a tuple of `shape(0,1)`, but the day group is optional, so shouldnt it still match the year group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.

The correct regex pattern is:
r'((?P<day>(\d?\d)?(\s|-|/|th|st|nd)?)?(?P<year>\d?\d?\d\d))'

The bracket for the year group was at the wrong position.

Comment: (\d{4}|\d{2})) If you want a 4 or 2 digit ending. 3 digits will match rn.